# Preference of storage in android

Tags: android, performance

I have created one app which creates one file on external memory, but when I install it on different devices the files are created in internal sdcard in some device and not created in external(Physical) sd card.

My question is that. How do we decide between the internal or external sdcard. 
Which has more preference to store file by default in android?

I use the 
`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "PolicyTaskfile"+"/filename.txt";`

It gives external or internal sdcard path depending on the device.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you do not get to pick.  It's up to the OEM to decide whether external storage is truly SD card or just an internal storage device (for example: eMMC).  With KitKat there is a notion of primary and secondary external storage, but no easy API to determine which you are using or which is really removable media.